# Getting event listeners related error from multipage html website

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

There's one problem I'm facing right now. In my application there are couple of html pages and they are connected internally through navigation links.
Now I'm getting some data on the homepage from an external api which is working fine. Now when I'm going to another html page it's throwing errors and showing the event listeners are missing as it's searching for those event listeners too. 
I'm compiling all my JavaScript codes into one bundle js file so all the script tags are same for all the html pages.                    For Example : I've two pages index.html and about. html    and the index.html page has an event listener document. queryselector('button').addEventListenr.. 
And now the script tag is  which I'm getting by bundling all the JavaScript files by webpack. Now about. html page has this same script tag and I'll fetch some other data to that page but when the page is loading the page is look for that button event listener and throwing errors. What should I do now?

Comment: Sounds like your code is looking for elements that aren't on the page and trying to attach event listeners to them. An outcome of using the same javascript on two pages with different elements perhaps. What's your question?

Comment: Actually I'm bundling all the JavaScript files into a single one. And as I said I'm getting data from an external api. Now what I'm trying to achieve is to get some amount of data on the first page, and get some other data on the other page from that same api.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've added an example, you can check it now.